# JSP upload file

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat, upload

My Tomcat is "**7.0.59**" and I want to upload file to server.

path as below:

```
tomcat7.0/[server folder]/upload
```

When I used localhost, file can upload to destination successfully.

But when I used other computer as client, it can't work!

(**Server can get file name and other information correctly**.)

Do I need to change the config or other setting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use multipart form in jsp 
and server side use following code.

for(FileItem item : multiparts){
    if(!item.isFormField()){
        String name = new File(item.getName()).getName();
        item.write( new File(UPLOAD_DIRECTORY + File.separator + name));
        request.setAttribute("photoname", name);
    }else{
        // here get value of other parameter which is not file type
        System.out.println(item.getFieldName()+" = "+item.getString());
    }
}
```